# photorec recovery of a deja dup recovery

Tags: deja-dup, photorec

is it possible?
I am attempting to recover deja dup files for a USB stick. I lost the files after an OS upgrade and then my USB stick broke (physically cracked the all in one chip). Really bad timing. I am using photorec to find the files. The USB stick was 16 gig with about 12 gig used space. 
This isn't going to work is it? Photorec does not preserve names. I have loads of .gz files, but they are all named fxxxxxxxx with random numbers.

EDIT
Inside files named fxxxxxxxxxx.tar.gz there are folders named multi-volume snapshot and inside there is another folder. I can see the name of my USB stick and then keep opening the folders like a russian doll until i get to a folder containing numbered files that cannot be opened

Comment: Looks like at least the file system is corrupted and needs to be repaired with `fsck`. You should not write to it any more in the mean time and perform a full backup of that drive, e. g. with Gnome Disk Utility.